# Is there any benchmark tool to test transaction speed?

Tags: benchmark

I'd like to know how many tx/sec does ethereum clients(like geth) in private network can process. Is there any benchmark software which can send many transactions or messages to ethereum clients?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest would be to try it your own.

use [new Date().getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

> The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970.

Example:

First unlock your account: `personal.unlockAccount(sender, password, time);`
then execute:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
var amount = 1;
var sender = personal.listAccounts[0]
var receiver = personal.listAccounts[0]
for (i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
   eth.sendTransaction({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount});
}

var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;
console.log('Execution time: ' + time);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any pre-written benchmark software.

I do know that the speed is directly related to how many CPU cores you have available, how much RAM you have and even the speed of the HDD.

I can get ~ 300 read transactions/second on a 2-core geth server.  Writes will certainly be slower than that.